# Reducability and decidability language

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

i am new to this course called Theory of Computation. And my teacher asked to solve this ... i dont know how to do it... please help

Consider the langauge  L_inf : A turing machine M belongs to L_inf if L(M) is an infinite set. Is this language turing recognizable?

Comment: Has your course covered Rice's Theorem?

Comment: No he didn't teach... :(